# Merging columns into a single column in a mysql view

Tags: mysql

How can I merge multiple columns into a single column in mysql view this way? 
can I get help please?

```
                        Source Table
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  id |  column1   |  column2   |  column3   |  column4   |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1  |   value1   |   value2   |   value4   |   value5   |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  2  |   value4   |   value7   |   value5   |   value9   |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Target view

```
+-----+-----------+
|  id |  columns  |
+-----+-----------+
|  1  |   value1  |
+-----+-----------+
|  1  |   value2  |
+-----+-----------+
|  1  |   value4  |
+-----+-----------+
|  1  |   value5  |
+-----+-----------+
|  2  |   value4  |
+-----+-----------+
|  2  |   value7  |
+-----+-----------+
|  2  |   value5  |
+-----+-----------+
|  2  |   value9  |
+-----+-----------+
```

This is what I tried:

```
CREATE VIEW viewtb AS
select id, Concat(column1, column2, column3, column4) as columns from maintb;
```

Obviously this didn't give me the result I want. 
Notice when columns are merged in the example table above, the corresponding ids are repeated too. How can I get this result in mysql? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `union`

```
 CREATE VIEW viewtb AS  
    select id, column1 as columns from  maintb
    union
    select id, column2  from maintb
    union
    select id, column3  from maintb
    union
    select id, column4  from maintb
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this works. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE_NAME

UNION ALL SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE_NAME

UNION ALL SELECT COLUMN3 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

But question is why would you need that? you can fetch the row at once and use the values and if you need to make relation between tables, you can use temporary table to store the fetched columns as rows. You need to go for `pivot-columns-rows` concept

Comment: thanks, Mandip. I need it to work with my php code. this is simpler for me.